# Computing the number of ordered pairs of integers $(k_1, k_2)$ such that $k_1k_2 \leq N$ for a given value of $N$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I'm asking this question in context with a more larger computer science problem.

Let $k_1$ and $k_2$ be two natural problems such that their product $k_1k_2 \leq N$. What is the number of possible values of the ordered pair $(k_1,k_2)$ such that the product is smaller than $N$?

I am thinking that it has to do with the number of divisors of numbers smaller than $N$, but don't know how to approach it. Since $k_1k_2 \leq N$ implies $k_1 \leq N/k_2$, we could look for all natural values of $k_2$, and then find an inequality for $k_1$; add up the number of possible values of $k_1$ for each mentioned case. However, this is a computational solution, and I am looking for an analytic one.

Comment: Computational and mathematical solutions are often one and the same; perhaps you meant an analytic solution, closed-form

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for every natural integer $n$, $d(n)$ is the number of (positive) divisors of $n$, then the number of ordered pairs $(k_1,k_2)$ such that $k_1k_2\leq N$ is simply

$$\sum_{n=1}^N d(n)$$

as for every divisor $k$ of $n$, $n/k$ also is an integer, and every ordered pair has been counted once and only once. This method is called filtering.

Comment: This is a good solution, Now, I am looking at this in an algorithmic standpoint: its complexity is $O(N \sqrt{N})$, so if you have any ideas that can be calculated more efficiently, it'd be great. I'll try to implement this solution either way. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can do it in $O(\ln(n)^2)$ by enumerating the pairs in a lexicographical order. For example, if $N = 7$, then you have $(1,1),\dots,(1,7)$, reject $(1,8)$ and move on to $(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)$ reject $(2,4)$ and move on to $(3,1)$ etc. If you're interested in only counting them then two variables and a counter should suffice. If you need help implementing it, I can help you.

Comment: Yeah, I found that solution. This can actually be improved to $O(\ln(n) \cdot \ln(\ln(n)))$, In my algorithm, since there was a third variable (it was a combinatorics modular arithmetic problem), the algorithm was solved with 3 simple FOR's.

Answer (score 0):

The number can be calculated by $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N d(n)$ where $d(n)$ is the number of positive divisors of $n$, but this can be more efficiently calculated as $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^N \left\lfloor \frac{N}{k}\right\rfloor$. This can be directly calculated from the problem. Just observe that for each possible value of $k_1$ there are $\left\lfloor \frac{N}{k_1}\right\rfloor$ possible values for $k_2$.

An even more efficient formula is $\displaystyle 2\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor} \left\lfloor \frac{N}{k}\right\rfloor - \lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor^2$

Approximating with high accuracy this sum is a well studied problem in Analytic Number Theory known as the [divisor problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function).

Comment: Very interesting solution, a $O([\sqrt{N}])$ approach